# Built a covariance matrix for GAM using magic and magic.post.proc, now how to calculate the normalized residuals?

Tags: lme4-nlme, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I used the example here ([Build a covariance matrix for GAM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33064/build-a-covariance-matrix-for-gam)) to modify my gam with a correlation matrix (temporal autocorrelation). I was able to follow the example completely. The problem I am having is figuring out how to calculate the normalized residuals so that I can plot the pacf and make sure I have no lingering residual autocorrelation and that my modification essentially worked. The documentation that I can find tells me that the normalized residuals are the standardized residuals pre-multiplied by the inverse square root factor of the estimated error correlation matrix. Normalized residuals I believe are an option in gamm4 but is not built in to the mgcv package.

Does anyone have a clue as to where I would start?

Edited 12/1/2017 13:20 CST: I ran the model with bam.
Here are my working residuals:
[image]
Here are my normalized residuals:
[image: normalized residuals]
I don't know if it looks like the corAR(1) was sufficient. Does it look like I need to figure out a way to use a corARMA process instead?

Comment: Could you use `bam()` to fit the model you want? It allows you to specify the AR(1) parameter via argument `rho` and the fitted model has a component `$std.rsd` which contains the residuals you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the rho argument only works with Gaussian-identity link models and I am working with a binomial distribution.

Comment: I don't believe that is true any longer. `?bam`, under the definition of argument `rho` now states "Also usable with other models when `discrete=TRUE`, in which case the AR model is applied to the working residuals and corresponds to a GEE approximation." So, you have to accept the discretization of covariates, but at least you should be able to estimate the model.

Comment: I just tried a modification of the example from `magic` but updated for binomial counts and estimated using `bam()`, and it seemed to work. I'll post something here shortly on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bam()` function in **mgcv** can now estimate models with non-Gaussian families with `rho` specified, where the known AR(1) is applied to working residuals of the fit. This is in the flavour of GEE models. For this to work for non-Gaussian families, the model must be fitted using the `discrete = TRUE` option.

Here is a modified version of the example discussed in the Q&A linked to above. The modification involves taking the original `y` computed in the example as the expectation of the response on the log-odds scale. I use this to simulated binomial count data with number of trials = 10, wherein the probability of success is a smooth function of covariate `x` contaminated with AR(1) noise ($\rho$ = 0.6).

```
library('mgcv')
library('nlme')
## simulate truth
set.seed(1)
n<-400
sig<-2
x <- 0:(n-1)/(n-1)
f <- 0.2*x^11*(10*(1-x))^6+10*(10*x)^3*(1-x)^10
## produce scaled covariance matrix for AR1 errors...
V <- corMatrix(Initialize(corAR1(.6),data.frame(x=x)))
Cv <- chol(V)  # t(Cv)%*%Cv=V
## Simulate AR1 errors ...
e <- t(Cv)%*%rnorm(n,0,sig) # so cov(e) = V * sig^2
## Observe truth + AR1 errors
y <- f + e

## simulate binomial counts
ybin <- rbinom(n, prob = plogis(y), size = 10)
## pull this into a form suitable for modelling
df <- data.frame(ysucc = ybin, yfail = 10 - ybin, x = x)
```

Then I estimate the binomial GAM using `bam()` and plug in the known value of of $\rho$.

```
m <- bam(cbind(ysucc, yfail) ~ s(x, k = 20), data = df, method = 'fREML',
         family = binomial, discrete = TRUE, rho = 0.6)
```

This produces:

```
> summary(m)

Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
cbind(ysucc, yfail) ~ s(x, k = 20)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.2361     0.1571   14.23   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
       edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(x) 8.801  10.79  152.4  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.438   Deviance explained = 45.7%
fREML = 838.53  Scale est. = 1         n = 400
```

The fitted model now contains the standardised residuals

```
> head(m$std.rsd)
[1] -0.6639582 -3.0220455  1.0812062  2.7469037  1.7084300 -2.3314401
```

And we can compare the ACFs of the default and the standardised residuals:

```
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
acf(residuals(m))
acf(m$std.rsd)
layout(1)
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question so that I could include pictures of my acf and pacf plots. Thank you so much for your help, by the way.

Comment: I don't know if it looks like the corAR(1) was sufficient. Does it look like I need to figure out a way to use a corARMA process instead?